# Recreate textlogo

Tags: tables, fonts, scaling

I am trying to recreate the logo beneath to the best of my abilities

[image]

So far my best results have produced the following image

[image]

There are a few problems with my solution though

- Is there a way to make the two lines on the right have the same height as the text on the left?
- In the same vein, can the vertically red line also be as tall as the text on the right?
- Apparently the font I am using is the "official" font, however it is not matching at all... I tried to reverse engineer the fonts, but found no free fonts that matched. Is there any way to obtain text that is more similar to the one above?

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{UiT-red}{HTML}{CB333B}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\huge UiT \textcolor{UiT-red}{$/$}}& NORGES ARKTISKE\\
    & UNIVERSITET\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "official"  font is definitely condensed and the "UiT" looks to be bold, but I don't know what it is.  If you have access to a pdf file with that logo in it, other questions here tell how to get that information. Regarding the size of "UiT", you can determine the size of `\huge` and then use `\fontfamily{...}\selectfont` to increase the size as necessary to match the 2-line height.  Good luck.

Comment: it is available as svg here  https://en.uit.no/ressurs/uit/webmain/img/Navnetrekk_engelsk.svg you could use that exactly rather than trying to fake it. or here without the English translation https://uit.no/ressurs/uit/webmain/img/Navnetrekk_norsk.svg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

The official logo is available as svg here

https://uit.no/ressurs/uit/webmain/img/Navnetrekk_norsk.svg

If you take the first three paths from that file they draw UiT

```
<path fill="#231F20" d="M13,27.6c-1.4,1.4-3.3,2.1-5.4,2.1c-2.2,0-4.1-0.7-5.5-2.1c-1.3-1.3-2-3.2-2-5.4V0h4.6v22.4
    c0,2.1,1.3,3.1,2.9,3.1c1.6,0,2.8-1,2.8-3.1V0H15v22.1C15,24.4,14.2,26.3,13,27.6z"/>
<path fill="#231F20" d="M22,4.9V0.1h4.8v4.8H22z M22.2,29.4V8.3h4.4v21.2H22.2z"/>
<path fill="#231F20" d="M42,4.2v25.2h-4.6V4.2h-4.9V0H47v4.2H42z"/>
```

So you can render them with Tikz using its svg path library

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\fill svg "M13,27.6c-1.4,1.4-3.3,2.1-5.4,2.1c-2.2,0-4.1-0.7-5.5-2.1c-1.3-1.3-2-3.2-2-5.4V0h4.6v22.4
            c0,2.1,1.3,3.1,2.9,3.1c1.6,0,2.8-1,2.8-3.1V0H15v22.1C15,24.4,14.2,26.3,13,27.6z";
\fill svg "M22,4.9V0.1h4.8v4.8H22z M22.2,29.4V8.3h4.4v21.2H22.2z";
\fill svg "M42,4.2v25.2h-4.6V4.2h-4.9V0H47v4.2H42z";
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```